# Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS error 'must be used only with select' when i'm doing it

Tags: database, prestashop-1.7

I have the same problem when i try to make a custom sql. My Prestashop version 1.7.3.4

```
$sql_order_detail = 'SELECT `id_order_detail`, `product_id`, `product_quantity`, `unit_price_tax_incl` FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail WHERE `id_order` = ' . $id_order;

$order_details = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($this->sql_order_detail, $array = true, $use_cache = 0);
```

I test my sql through  logs and phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT `id_order_detail`, `product_id`, `product_quantity`, `unit_price_tax_incl` FROM ps_order_detail WHERE `id_order` = 24
```

The error is:

```
stderr: Db->executeS() must be used only with select, show, explain or describe queries,
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using:
(mysteriously)

```
$sql = new DbQuery();
$sql->select('*');
$sql->from('order_detail');
$sql->where('id_order = ' . $id_order);
$order_details = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
```